# Can i open a server using assembly, if i can how and what basic commands do i need to know

Tags: assembly, server

I want to open a server using assembly for my school project, i only know 16bit assembly and i'm pretty sure i cant open a server with that so i started learning NASM but before i go though all this i need to know if it is even possible and some basic commands for opening a server in assembly

i already searched a little bit on the internet and i heard you can make a SQL server but i don't know if that's true and i have no idea how to open a SQL server.

i don't need a complicated server just a server that'll respond with hello or somthing

Comment: What do you mean by "open" exactly? `Is it possible?` Since C effectively compiles to assembly and it's most likely possible in C, its therefore also possible in assembly.

Comment: i don't know i'm new to servers. i know c ill try to look into opening a server with c before assembly. thanks anyways

Comment: @appeleleqqa What does “open a server” mean for you?  I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: by "opening a server" i mean creating one, creating a server than can respond to a request from a client. like an ICPM  socket, a server that'll respond to a request.

Comment: "i only know 16bit assembly and i'm pretty sure i cant open a server " - this is not principally true, you can create "server" even with 8 bit computer. Although it sounds like you did learn x86-16 assembly so far, probably under DOS, and running it under some VM or emulator, which makes direct connection to network card (being in hold of 32 or 64 bit modern operating system) impossible. But maybe some emulators/VMs provide enough emulation to even run some old SW providing one of the common network interfaces... but all that is quite cumbersome...(it's simpler to write 32/64b asm with C libs)

Comment: I mean, it doesn't sound like you hit the true reason why creating server in x86-16 is cumbersome, sounds more like you have no idea yet, how these things work, and you will get soon surprised how many extra layers can be involved (unless you want to reinvent the wheel completely and talk to network card in completely direct way, like writing your own driver, but that means you would need documentation of particular HW network card)... Check some simple "server" (not SQL database), maybe some example like https://www.ultimatepp.org/reference$SocketServer$en-us.html ... and get deep into libs.

Comment: Then pick some abstraction layer depending how much code you want to write in assembly, and verify you have the libraries handling the rest of the things, like that you are able to link them with your main assembly and call their API...  ... and maybe I would still start with some simple serial link test in x86-16 (I guess some VMs/emus allow to connect to serial port of the emulated machine, so you can then talk with your "server" from host OS), that's probably most trivial stuff, as serial links were used for all kind of things back in ~1990, also for games multiplayer for DOS games...